# Ordenar Menu desplegable HTML5/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actualmente tengo un menú sencillo con uno de las opciones desplegables ya que solo necesito que esa opción despliegue. El problema es que no logro que la opción desplegable me queda en la posición correcta que es la tercera, sino que queda de ultima. Adicionalmente tengo un problema con la dimensión de las opciones.

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar para colocarla en el orden correcto estaría agradecido. A continuación el código:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    //background-color: #ccc9c9;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>

<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  //overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
 <a href="#about">About</a>
 <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">Tracking</button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#"><font color="black">opcion 1</font></a>
     <a href="#"><font color="black">opcion 2</font></a>
     <a href="#"><font color="black">opcion 3</font></a>
   </div>
 </div>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar un id a `About` y manipular el css asi:

```css
#about {
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
.dropbtn {
    //background-color: #ccc9c9;
    color: black;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
</style>

<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  //overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav a:not(:first-child) {display: none;}
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .topnav.responsive {position: relative;}
  .topnav.responsive .icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
  .topnav.responsive a {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
  <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
 <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="dropbtn">Tracking</button>
   <div class="dropdown-content">
     <a href="#"><font color="black">opcion 1</font></a>
     <a href="#"><font color="black">opcion 2</font></a>
     <a href="#"><font color="black">opcion 3</font></a>
   </div>
 </div>
  <a id="about" href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div style="padding-left:16px">
  <h2>Responsive Topnav Example</h2>
  <p>Resize the browser window to see how it works.</p>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
    if (x.className === "topnav") {
        x.className += " responsive";
    } else {
        x.className = "topnav";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Y si quisiera que el news aparezca despues del tracking? Gracias por tu respuesta